# publish vs 2010 website to local iis

Tags: asp.net, publishing

I struggling on hours to accomplish this.
I have created a web site in **VS 2010.** Now I need to host this on my local IIS(My development PC) for the testing.

I created a web site on `inetmgr` and publish the web site using VS. Now I can access it. It is Fine.

But it is not functioning properly now.
I have a web form and once I submit it do some steps which I coded in my code behind and redirect to another page (This is what needs to be happen).

But now it is not happening.Once I click on the button it will reload the page.

In side the publish folder I can only see the `.aspx` files. Cannot find `.cs` files.

What is the wrong I did here.
Have I missed something?
If you can plesae provide me some urls to compete step by step guidance.

**Edit**
Default.aspx.

```
        string filePathVal = ((TextBox)CustomerDataPanel.FindControl("FilePath")).Text;

        if (!File.Exists(filePathVal))
        {
            errorMsgPannel.Visible = true;
            return;
        }

        Response.Redirect("result.aspx?status=success", false);
```

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: Whatever the steps I took, I have state above.

Comment: Please provide some code; you dont's see cs files because if you build your website they are builded inside site dll.

Comment: Did you mean code inside default.aspx and default.cs. This site is working well when I run it through the visual studio.

Comment: When you publish the web application, the .cs files are added to the bin directory as pointed out above.  You should see your website structure, i.e. folders, aspx files, .css etc.  Can you post the code that you have in the click event of the button please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I Fixed my issue. But still have doubt why previous approach did not work. I used [Creating a Web Project as an IIS Virtual Root](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1zz9df4%28v=vs.100%29.aspxs) this to fix my issue. :)